# Movilizer - set the password of a cloud user programmatically via Web Service Call

Tags: mobile, movilizer

By assigning a movelet to a new user it is possible to create new users on the cloud. Is it possible to set the password programmatically via Web Service Call to the movilizer cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning a Movelet to a not existing participant a new participant will be created. It is also possible to define a password for participants, via webservice, this is how it works:

```
<participantConfiguration deviceAddress="deviceAddress" passwordHashType="1" passwordHashValue="myTopSecretPassword" />
```

It is only possible to define a password via webService, there is no option define a participant password via MEL.

It is also possible to define a password of types:

- md5
- SHA256
- SHA512